# PHP & cUrl - POST problems in while loop

Tags: php, loops, curl, libcurl

I have a while loop, with cUrl inside. (I can't use curl_multi for various reasons.) The problem is that cUrl seems to save the data it POSTS after each loop traversal. For instance, if parameter X is One the first loop through, and if it's Two the second loop through, cUrl posts: "One,Two". It should just POST "Two".(This is despite closing and unsetting the curl handle.)

Here's a simplified version of the code (with unecessary info stripped out):

```
<?php   
  while(true){

           // code to form the $url. this code is local to the loop. 
          // so the variables should be "erased" and made new for each 
         // loop through.

    $ch = curl_init();
    $userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $resultTable = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//table");

           // $resultTable is 20 the first time through the loop,
           // and 0 everytime thereafter because the POSTing doesn't work right 
           //with the "saved" parameters.
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

---

EDIT

Michael was right. I needed to unset $fields/$fields_string. The new data was concatenated onto the old data.

I don't understand why this happens, though. $fields is a local variable in the loop. **Shouldn't it be removed from the stack once the loop ends, and then it'd be created a new?**

Comment: I'd like to see the code creating $url, $fields and $fields_string.

Comment: It's a best practice to explicitly declare your variables before you use them, even though PHP doesn't require that you do this.  e.g. Place `$fields = null;` at the beginning of whichever scope is appropriate.

Comment: Loops do not have their own local stack. If you have a loop like for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++){ //do stuff inside loop } echo $i; then the echo $i will print 9 even though it's outside of the loop.

Comment: php does not use block scoping

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the $fields_string and $fields to see their values at each loop iteration? Perhaps one of them isn't getting cleared. Since you're using curl_init/curl_close each time, the problem is likely not in curl itself.

Comment: That was it. If you could answer the EDIT question, I'd be eternally, irrevocably, unmatchably grateful.

Comment: Sarah covered it really well above. It's really frustrating for me too - coming from a C background, not having a well defined scope within loops is annoying. I just learned to always initialise the local variables within loops. One place where PHP does have good scope is functions - which is perhaps where you should have placed the curl code anyways, much cleaner in a nice "getSiteData($url,$fields)" function which would have copied the $fields and $url into the local scope.